# Limit on number of basis vectors for a d-dimensional lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

is there a limit to how many basis vectors one can have when decorating a d-dimensional lattice? For example, if I have a crystal structure in 2D that has an underlying lattice, is it permissible to decorate it with more than two basis vectors? This is just a sanity check since I haven't dealt with complicated crystal structures.

Comment: Just to clarify, by 'basis' vector, do you basically just mean the position of an atom in the unit cell?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear